# MVC Actionlink or possible routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, actionlink

I have had a number of challenges with routing in my application and with a lot of frustration and articles here, I thought I had nailed it but having now tested my app, I have a final glitch.

I moved the default to the bottom and the purchase route to the top, I then found that due to the different parameters, I needed to create a route for each page other it broke something.

The last problem I have is that once you click on a menu bar item which inherited from a layout page (any click from from the first page works correctly), you get the wrong result on anything other than Home on the susequent pages.

First page gives link like :

http://localhost:34396/Products/2/1

Subsequent pages gives:

http://localhost:34396/Products/2/1 for every link on the menu bar apart from Home.

Any ideas really appreciated, its driving me nuts and anything I do just breaks it even more, not sure if its because of the way I am doing the links or its a fundemental error in my routing.

Cheers,
Steve.

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu" class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Products", "Products", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Existing Customers", "Existing", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Claims", "Claims", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQ", "FAQ", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


routes.MapRoute(
"Purchase", // Route name
"Purchase/{AgentId}/{ProductId}/{SchemeId}/{CoverTypeId}/{CoverLevelId/{SubAgentId}",     // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Purchase", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional, ProductId = UrlParameter.Optional, SchemeId = UrlParameter.Optional, CoverTypeId = UrlParameter.Optional, CoverLevel = UrlParameter.Optional, SubAgent = UrlParameter.Optional } ,  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
"Products", // Route name
"Products/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional,
subAgent = 0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

        routes.MapRoute(
"MoreInfo_Annual", // Route name
"MoreInfo_Annual/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "MoreInfo_Annual", AgentId = 
UrlParameter.Optional, SubAgent = 0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
"FAQ", // Route name
"FAQ/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "FAQ", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional, SubAgent = 
0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
"Existing", // Route name
"Existing/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Existing", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional,   
SubAgent = 0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
"ContactUs", // Route name
"ContactUs/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "ContactUs", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional,     
SubAgent = 0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
"Claims", // Route name
"Claims/{AgentId}/{SubAgentId}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Claims", AgentId = UrlParameter.Optional,   
SubAgent = 0 },  // Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);

            routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{AgentShortCode}/{referid}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", AgentShortCode = "Steve", referid = 1  
},   
// Parameter defaults
new[] { "BrochureWare.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Html.RouteLink, and specify the name of the route you want to link to, to force ASP.NET to pick the route you want to use.

So you could do something like this:

```
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu" class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Home", "Default", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Products", "Products", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Existing Customers", "Existing", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Claims", "Claims", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("FAQ", "FAQ", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
            <li>@Html.RouteLink("Contact Us", "ContactUs", new { AgentId = ViewData["AgentId"], SubAgentId = ViewData["ReferId"] })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, partially worked, but still getting issues once you navigate down a level, I think its a routing issue overall, but I have worked around it by having two layouts, one for the main and one for the all other pages.  Works a treat and I may revisit when less annoyed with how many hours I have wasted on it.